# Firebase FirAnalyticsConnector Build Error

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, cocoapods, firebase-analytics

After running pod install with:

```
  pod 'Firebase/Analytics'
```

I am now getting the following build error:

> ld: framework not found FirAnalyticsConnector clang error: linker
> command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

I have tried removing FirAnalyticsConnector from the Build Setting's Other Linker Flags (as similar questions' answers suggested), but it does not solve the issue

Any ideas as to why I am getting this build error when I was previously able to build the project?

Comment: Try opening the Xcode project file in a text editor and search for `FIRAnalyticsConnector`

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix this by removing the Firebase pod completely, then reinstalling.

I first removed it from my podfile, did another pod install, then deleted all references in my code (and Other Linker Flags). I also had some old (previously Twitter, then Google) Fabric code.

Once I got the project to build and run without that cocoapod, I tried installing it fresh following Firebase documentation and it works with no errors now.